# GIT - Pushing from server to GitHub triggers a Pull error

Tags: git

I am quite new to git versioning so excuse me in advance if the query may seem trivial.

I have a Django project on my local computer and I pushed it on a GitHub repository.
I cloned the repository on the online linux server hosting the project. So far so good. Due to the tight schedule, I need to work on, I made some patches directly on the online code.

Then i decided to push these changes on the github repository so that i can pull them on my local computer and start implementing new changes to push back on GitHub at a later stage.

Once i run the push command from the server to GitHub an error informing me to consider pulling before pushing as another user (the local one) is pushing on the same GitHub repository is displayed.

My questions are:

1. is it safe to pull from GitHub on the server? I am afraid the patches I have applied directly on the server will disappear as a result of pulling from GitHub (which does not contain the patches)
2. if it is safe to pull, what is the correct command sequence? Pull, add ., commit, push?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general answer is : NO, do not pull straight from your production server some unreviewed changes.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is : NO, do not pull straight from your production server some unreviewed changes.

---

I assume you have created a commit with your changes, on your hosting server, on its local `master` branch.

One way to share the files you have on your hosting server is : push them to a new branch

```
# this will create a new branch 'woops_I_coded_on_a_live_production_server' :
git push origin master:woops_I_coded_on_a_live_production_server
```

From your local machine, you can then use that commit to integrate the changes to the master branch.

---

Another way to copy content from your production server is : copy the files.

Run a `tar -czf archive.tgz codedir/` on your production server, copy `archive.tgz` back to your machine, and handle things from there.

Comment: i tried the following commands:
`git init`
`git add .`
`git commit -m "some text`
`git checkout -b new-branch`
`git push origin new-branch`
but i receive the following error:
Enumerating objects: 984, done.
Counting objects: 100% (984/984), done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads
fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'my github repository'